# Why can't I see any gym or pokestop

Tags: pokemon-go

Yesterday, it was fine, but now I can't play because I can't gyms or Pokestops. My friends can still see them though.

Comment: This is an amazingly poorly written question

Comment: I think you're just having connection issues

Comment: what do you mean cant see anything? cant see any pokemon? cant see any pokestops or gyms? is everything just blank without houses and roads or is it just black? You have barely given ANY information

Answer (score 0):

One of the reasons this occurs is a bad connection. The other one is that you are rooted/jailbroken.

You can fix this by using TSProtector or similar JB/root hiding software.